# Asbestos in concrete foundation

Tags: foundation, asbestos

Clear and simple: is it possible that there is asbestos in the poured concrete foundation of a US home built in 1951?

I am worried about this, because I want to drill holes in the basement concrete walls and I'm worried that I might release asbestos fibers if it was added to the concrete. I read somewhere that asbestos was added to concrete in order to strengthen it, but I don't know if this was the case in concrete used as the foundation of a home.

Comment: It should be noted that if there *is*, it really isn't a hazard as it's encased in concrete.

Comment: @DA01 - Yes, until you start drilling holes in it and making dust...

Answer (score 3):

Possible, yes.

Likely in a residential foundation, no.

To know for sure, spend money testing - unfortunately the only way to know, as there are no visible clues in this application, evidently.

http://www.concreteconstruction.net/industrial-projects/asbestos-and-old-buildings.aspx

Comment: +1 but also to add, concrete dust on its own is bad for you, albeit not as bad as asbestos. In either case dust masks, thorough cleaning and mitigation need to be dealt with. Just speculating, the only difference with asbestos is you'd go to a wet procedure and/or a negative pressure setup.

Answer (score -1):

No never not once in poured concrete. Do not listen to any tales of otherwise.  It serves no purpose in poured concrete.

Comment: You give yourself that username and then proceed to disseminate faulty information? Did you even look at the other answer?